# How to set app logo using the config and env files?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

If the logo path is `public/assets/logos/logo.png`, what should the value of the key `APP_LOGO=` be? And then how do I call it whenever I need it in some pages?

Assuming I also set that value in app.php config (And what should be the default value there as well?)

`'logo' => env('APP_LOGO', <what default value here?>),`

Comment: if your `APP_LOGO` is not set in the env file then you can put a default logo path in the app.php

Comment: Thank you, and the paths are all relative? in my case it's `public/assets/logos/logo.png`? Or something else?

Comment: Environment configuration is meant to be used in cases where it will be different between environments. In your case if it's going to be the same path for all environments you should just do `'logo' => 'public/assets/logos/logo.png'` or `'logo' => public_path('assets/logo.png')`

Comment: I think you can use `assets()` in the app.php but in the .env file, you will have to give a relative path or you can put like `/public/assets/logos/logo.png` so it will accessible like `<YOUR_DOMAIN>/public/assets/logos/logo.png`.

Comment: thank you guys, I set it both in `.env` as `APP_LOGO` and then referred to it in the `app.php` as `'app_logo'=>env..`, now inside any file that I need to get that logo, how do I do it? For example from the login or register page